# Ivy extra attributes xmlns

Tags: java, xsd, dependencies, ivy

1. What are the available URIs that could be specified for ivy extra attributes?

   The Ivy manual pages allow us to use the URI

   > xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra"

   which would allow us the following free-form use of extra attributes.

   ```
   <ivy-module version="2.0"
     xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">

     <info
       organisation="mitt.wit"
       module="EtchASketch"
       revision="47-pct"
       e:reset="true"
       >
   ```

   Are there other URIs available for use? For example, could we do

   ```
   <ivy-module version="2.0"
     xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra"
     xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
     xmlns:ivy="antlibrg.apache.ivy.ant"

     <info
       organisation="mitt.wit"
       module="EtchASketch"
       revision="47-pct"
       e:reset="true"
       ivy:home="${springfield.mittychusetts}"
       m:daven="sometimes"
       >
   ```

   What other URIs could I use?
2. If there are other URIs available, where could I find their list of allowable attributes (from an XSD perhaps)? Like

   ```
   m:classifier
   ivy:home
   ```

   Or, perhaps, anything goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may use any qualified attribute (in effect any URI since ivy XSD doesn't have a target namespace). The [Ivy XSD](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd) allows for `<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />`.
2. It would depend on the URI. In general, one way to start is to find out the XSD which corresponds to the URI and look for all the global attributes declarations. If that is not an option, module specific documentation should also help. Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897672/location-of-xsd-for-ant-ivy-lib-antliborg-apache-ivy-ant-for-ide-autocomplete) for other ideas. If it is really important, and all of the above don't work, maybe looking at some source code (e.g. I couldn't find an XSD for ivy/maven but I ran into this source code [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/parser/m2/PomModuleDescriptorBuilder.java?view=markup) which is related to Maven, has m:classifier in it so maybe the other might be applicable as well).